# Performance regarding nodejs as a server backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

Will it be a good idea to use **nodejs** as server backend for making an interactive website which can respond to thousands of client requests.

Let's say i want to create a facebook like social networking site instead of **php** using nodejs as the backend server connectivity. Can **nodejs** be able to perform well in this scenario?

And please, tell me some great websites which is of nodejs.

Comment: it all depends on how you code it, but yes nodejs is really fast for processing many "short" requests

Comment: Websites like Facebook aren't built on one single technology, but a multitude of technologies and languages. This question is a little too broad for SO. You should research the different technologies available, their use cases and consider which ones are appropriate for your application.

Answer (score 8):

**What is nodejs?**

In short, nodejs is (should be used for) I/O driven websites and when you have something CPU intensive requests, nodejs is not a good solution. The whole architecture of nodejs is based on single-threaded non-blocking asynchronous model and it is where nodejs shines.

See this way: One request never blocks the next. That being said, thousands of requests can be processed at a time and yes, in a better way. But imagine the same, where thousands of requests are CPU intensive and there is a single-thread. Do you see the problem?

The following figure excerpted from [toptal](http://www.toptal.com/nodejs/why-the-hell-would-i-use-node-js) should be useful.

[image: Nodejs versus traditional servers]

There is one very good metaphor to explain how nodejs work. Please read the [nodeJS for beginners](http://debuggable.com/posts/understanding-node-js:4bd98440-45e4-4a9a-8ef7-0f7ecbdd56cb) for complete detail but I am excerpting for reference here.

> To understand, imagine your code is the king, and node is his
>   army of servants.
>
> The day starts by one servant waking up the king and asking him if he
>   needs anything. The king gives the servant a list of tasks and goes
>   back to sleep a little longer. The servant now distributes those tasks
>   among his colleagues and they get to work.
>
> Once a servant finishes a task, he lines up outside the kings quarter
>   to report. The king lets one servant in at a time, and listens to
>   things he reports. Sometimes the king will give the servant more tasks
>   on the way out.
>
> Life is good, for the king's servants carry out all of his tasks in
>   parallel, but only report with one result at a time, so the king can
>   focus. *

**What big companies are using nodejs?**

Walmart, ebay, linkedin, Yahoo, mozilla. Don't let whether other are using or not fool you though. Your requirement should dictate what you want not what is "hot" in market.